# mvn exec:java on an sbt project

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I have a scala project that I'm doing an `sbt publish` on. It gives me some artifacts:

```
/maven/repo/com/davez0r/proj_2.10/vers/proj_2.10-vers.jar
/maven/repo/com/davez0r/proj_2.10/vers/proj_2.10-vers.pom
...others...
```

Now I want to run a class inside of that jar:

```
$ mvn -f /maven/repo/com/davez0r/proj_2.10/vers/ exec:java 
      -Dexec.mainClass="com.davez0r.App"
```

This doesn't work:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /maven/repo/com/davez0r/proj_2.10/vers/pom.xml
```

Ok, I can point `mvn` at the `pom` file that `sbt` generated:

```
$ mvn -f /maven/repo/com/davez0r/proj_2.10/vers/proj_2.10-vers.pom exec:java 
      -Dexec.mainClass="com.davez0r.App"
```

Now it finds my dependencies, but it doesn't find the `jar` sitting next to the `pom`:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.davez0r.App
```

I can create a separate project whose only dependency is this set of artifacts, but that seems unnecessary. I'll post the details of this as an answer.

Is there any way to run directly from the repo via `mvn`? Do I have something set incorrectly in my `pom`?

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.davez0r</groupId>
  <artifactId>proj_2.10</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <description>proj</description>
  <version>vers</version>
  <name>proj</name>
  <organization>
    <name>com.davez0r</name>
  </organization>
  <dependencies>...</dependencies>
</project>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can get this working by creating a separate `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <repositories>
    <url>http://davez0r.com/maven/</url>
    ...
  </repositories>

  <groupId>com.davez0r</groupId>
  <artifactId>launcher</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.davez0r</groupId>
      <artifactId>proj_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>vers</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then I can `mvn exec:java` in the directory containing the above file and it runs fine.